# What is a good modern task load measurement?

Tags: survey, measurement

I will be conducting an experiment during which I need to measure mental load.

After some research I decided on subjective measurements, as I can't obtain the equipment needed to attempt objective measurements.

I came across the [NASA TLX test](http://human-factors.arc.nasa.gov/groups/TLX/) which seems to be what I need, but it looks a little bit dated.

Are there any more modern survey/measurement techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this question takes me back a bit - we used NASA TLX in an experiment about ten years ago. I think at the time it was chosen for having the best test-retest reliability amongst methods. This was from a time when I was working on a project for DARPA, and I note that the project office that we worked for have released [a book on the subject](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0739112015), although I can't vouch for the quality of this book as I don't own it. Others are:

SWAT (Subjective Workload Assessment Technique), MCH (Modified
Cooper Harper Scale), ZEIS (Sequential Judgement Scale), and the Bedford Workload Rating Scale. Which of these is best will depend on the specifics of your experiment.

Quite a useful review can be found in [Chapter 3 of a NATO Technical Report](http://ftp.rta.nato.int/public//PubFullText/RTO/TR/RTO-TR-021///TR-021-03.pdf), although this is a few years old now too (2004 I think).

Comment: NATO's technical report really helped me along. It's a great reading on the subject. Thanks!